# Find mean grouped by column in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark

I have a dataframe such as:

| Col1 | Value |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 20 |
| 1 | 30 |
| 1 | 20 |
| 1 | 10 |
| 0 | 10 |
| 2 | 30 |

I want to calculate mean and group by Col1, so that the result is:

| Col1 | Value2 |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 15 |
| 1 | 20 |
| 2 | 30 |

I don't know how to get the result (the aggregated mean). One additional problem is that when I try df.groupBy("Col1") the 0 value does not appear.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In PySpark version 3, the following code accomplishes exactly what you have pictured above.

```
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.1.1-amzn-0
      /_/

Using Python version 3.7.10 (default, Jun  3 2021 00:02:01)
>>> from pyspark.sql.functions import avg
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([
... {"Col1": 0, "Value": 20},
... {"Col1": 1, "Value": 30},
... {"Col1": 1, "Value": 20},
... {"Col1": 1, "Value": 10},
... {"Col1": 0, "Value": 10},
... {"Col1": 2, "Value": 30}
... ])

>>> df.show()
+----+-----+
|Col1|Value|
+----+-----+
|   0|   20|
|   1|   30|
|   1|   20|
|   1|   10|
|   0|   10|
|   2|   30|
+----+-----+

>>> grouped = df.groupBy("Col1").agg(avg("Value").alias("Value2"))
>>> grouped.show()
+----+------+
|Col1|Value2|
+----+------+
|   1|  20.0|
|   2|  30.0|
|   0|  15.0|
+----+------+
```

If you do not need the aggregated column re-aliased to "Value2", you can skip the import and just do `grouped = df.groupBy("Col1").avg("Value")` and your averaged column will just be called "avg(Value)".

If this "does not work" according to your example, please provide the exact code (or a minimal reproducible example) that can be inspected as to why it might not be returning desired results.